# Escaping in PHP does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, escaping, echo

I have this snippet in `Wordpress`:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      echo " <span class=blabla>
<a href="<?php echo home_url() . '/author/' . get_the_author_meta( 'user_login', wp_get_current_user()->ID ); ?>" >My personal page</a>

        </span> "; } ?>
```

So because it has two `echo`'s, I used this:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      echo " <span class=blabla>
<a href=\"home_url() . '/author/' . get_the_author_meta( 'user_login', wp_get_current_user()->ID ); \" >My personal page</a>

        </span> "; } ?>
```

For some reason it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why the downvote? Explain please. Don't understand some guys here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a couple of syntax errors there.

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo "<span class=blabla>"
       . "<a href=\"" . home_url() . "/author/"
       . get_the_author_meta('user_login', wp_get_current_user()->ID)
       . "\" >My personal page</a></span> "; 
}
```

To double check if a file has errors on it, run this in the command line:

```
php -l [filename]
```

It should return

```
No syntax errors detected in [filename]
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it readable, separate PHP from HTML and split long lines

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    $url  = home_url() . '/author/'; 
    $url .= get_the_author_meta( 'user_login', wp_get_current_user()->ID );
?>
<span class=blabla>
    <a href="<?php echo $url ?>">My personal page</a>
</span>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
    <span class="blabla">
        <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/author/' . get_the_author_meta( 'user_login', get_current_user_id() ) ) ?>">My personal page</a>
    </span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene, appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the strings before `home_url()`, and have quotes after the concat operator `.` in  `->ID ).`

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  echo " <span class=blabla>
<a href=\"".home_url() . '/author/' . get_the_author_meta( 'user_login', 
    wp_get_current_user()->ID )." \" >My personal page</a>
    </span> "; } ?>
```

Comment: Almost there. It does not recognize home_url...

Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Good catch!  It should recognize `home_url` now.

Comment: The answer or comment?  :)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      echo ' <span class="blabla"><a href="'.home_url() . '/author/' . get_the_author_meta( "user_login", wp_get_current_user()->ID ).'>My personal page</a></span> '; } 
?>
```